# Fill in the lakes

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given the topography of land in ASCII picture format, figure out where lakes would go and fill them in.  Assume an infinite amount of rain.

### example

**input**

```
         #               
         ##              
      # ####             
#    #########           
##  ###########          
## #############   ####  
## ##############  ##### 
################# #######
#########################
#########################
```

**output**

```
         #               
         ##              
      #@####             
#@@@@#########           
##@@###########          
##@#############@@@####  
##@##############@@##### 
#################@#######
#########################
#########################
```

The input will contain only spaces and `#` marks.  Each line will be the same length.  The output should be the identical `#` pattern with spaces where water would accumulate filled in with `@` marks.

The bottom input row will always be all # marks.  There will be no holes or overhangs in the land.  Shortest code wins.

Comment: This seems a bit easy.  I think we should also have to display the number of lake units `@` that were filled in.

Comment: @mellamokb: This would be roughly a `([char[]]"$a"-eq'@').Count` here. Not that much too add. Agreed on this being a little too easy, though. Doesn't fall into the realm of what I'd downvote, though.

Comment: Related on Stack Overflow: [Code Golf: Running Water](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1766675/2509). One of LiraNuna's better one, I thought.

Comment: So do we also have to handle underground caverns, which may have air above the water level like the Running Water puzzle?  That makes things a little more challenging and I think should definitely be an example use case.

Comment: @dmckee: That one wasn't as easy as this though.

Comment: @mellamokb: I think we agreed some time ago that the questions from SO are not to be replicated here. Mostly because there are already solutions there.

Comment: @joey: No. The possibility of the caves seems to rule our a simple regexp solution to the LiraNuna one.

Comment: Since # and @ are both massive characters, I suggest using . instead of @, which gives better pictures, IMHO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### sed -r, <strike>27</strike> 24 (27 with `-r`)

24 (27):

```
:;s/(#|@) ( *#)/\1@\2/;t
```

<strike>27 (30):</strike>

```
:e;s/([#@]) ( *#)/\1@\2/;te
```

Competes with the better of the two perl solutions

Comment: `#|@` would be one char shorter

Comment: You should add 3 to the count for the -r flag. You can cut off two from removing the `e`s, and another from S.Mark's suggestion to get back to 27 though.

Comment: @Nabb thanks, discovered something with the empty label

Comment: I tried sed before, but failed

Answer (score 8):

### Perl, 25

```
s/# +#/$_=$&;y| |@|;$_/ge
```

Comment: I added a character count. Please look whether it's actually correct, as it might need to include some interpreter flags (`-p` maybe?).

Comment: i dont know perl language, but i can feel its power :)

Comment: Actually it needs ` -pe` to function on my box, so that should be an additional 4 chars. Or does the `e` not count and thus only 3 additional chars required?

Comment: Don't need the e, like I mentioned elsewhere, for the same reasons.  :)

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes on this approach by inlining the change to `$&` without assigning to `$_`: `s/# +#/$&=~y! !@!r/ge`

Comment: [Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoicy8jICsjLyQmPX55ISAhQCFyL2dlIiwiYXJncyI6Ii1wIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIgICAgICAgICAjICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgICAgICAjIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgICAjICMjIyMgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4jICAgICMjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAgXG4jIyAgIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMgICAgICAgICAgXG4jIyAjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjICAgIyMjIyAgXG4jIyAjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyAgIyMjIyMgXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyAjIyMjIyMjXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIn0=)

Answer (score 6):

### Perl (>= v5.9.5), 24 chars

Run with `perl -p`:

```
1while s/#.*\K (?=\S)/@/
```

[This requires Perl 5.9.5 or later to use the special escape `\K`.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl595delta.html#%5cK-escape)

Comment: Except that if Nabb is correct, you need to count ` -p` as 3 chars, bringing your total to 27. And it actually requires ` -pe`. I don't know the full rules about flags, so not sure the `e` counts.

Comment: Wouldn't actually need the e, if you simply hit enter and type it in afterwards, or put the code in a file and run it.  So -e isn't really needed.  :)

Answer (score 3):

### Windows PowerShell, 36 <s>74</s> <s>138</s>

```
$input-replace'(?<!^ *) (?! *$)','@'
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), 10 bytes

Retina is (much) newer than this challenge. But this solution is too neat not to post it:

```
T` `@`#.*#
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGAgYEBgIy4qIw&input=ICAgICAgICAgIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAjIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICMgIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAKIyAgICAjIyMjIyMjIyMgICAgICAgICAgIAojIyAgIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMgICAgICAgICAgCiMjICMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMgICAjIyMjICAKIyMgIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMgICMjIyMjIAojIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyAjIyMjIyMjCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMKIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIw)

This is simply a transliteration stage which replaces spaces with `@`, but the operation is restricted to matches of `#.*#`, i.e. characters which are surrounded by land on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.8, 30 characters

```
#!ruby -p
gsub(/# +#/){$&.tr" ","@"}
```

If anyone has an idea why this doesn't work in Ruby 1.9 (tested with 1.9.2p0 and 1.9.2p204), even though the documentation says [it should work](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001425), let me know!

Comment: That's really weird, adding in `$_=$_.` to the start of the second line makes it work in 1.9.2 so it's something to do with `Kernel.gsub`.  Rubinius also fails without explicitly adding `$_`.

Comment: According to 1.9.1 NEWS log, Kernel#getc, #gsub, #sub are deprecated.

Comment: I think you can count this as 30 (27 + 3 for needing the `-p` flag). The hash-bash and name of the interpreter doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>95</s> 92 bytes

```
for s in S.split('\n'):b=s.find('#');e=s.rfind('#');print s[:b]+s[b:e].replace(' ','@')+s[e:]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|εγć?D¨ð'@:sθJJ,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5tzWc5uPtNu7HFpxeIO6g1XxuR1eXjr//yvAgLICKuBCyChjlVEGSqBJcYFNUYYBZBkQT1kZixRIRlkZVQpCYcjAjADJoAGYQkwZZYIyAA)

**Explanation:**

```
|            # Take all input-lines as list
 ε           # For each line:
  γ          #  Split the line into chunks of consecutive equal characters
             #   i.e. " ##   # " → [' ','##','   ','#',' ']
   ć         #  Split into head and the rest of the list
             #   i.e. [' ','##','   ','#',' '] → ['##','   ','#',' '] and ' '
    ?        #  Print this head
   D         #  Duplicate the rest of the list
    ¨        #  Remove the last element
             #   i.e. ['##','   ','#',' '] → ['##','   ','#']
     ð'@:    #  Replace every space with a "@"
             #   i.e. ['##','   ','#'] → ['##','@@@','#']
     sθ      #  Swap so the duplicated list is at the top, and take the last item as is
             #   i.e. ['##','   ','#',' '] → ' '
         JJ  #  Join the lists and individual items in the list together to a single string
             #   i.e. ['##','@@@','#'] and ' ' → "##@@@# "
           , #  Print with trailing new-line
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
aR:`#.*#`_TRs'@
```

Takes input as a multiline string via command-line argument: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/McgqQVlPSzkhPiSoWN3h////CjCgrIAKuBAyylhllIESaFJcykgyKHJcIJ4yAqDKKCujSkEoDBmYESAZNABTiCmjTFAGAA) (Alternately, specify the `-rn` flags and change the first `a` to `g`, and you can give input via stdin: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PcgqQVlPSzkhPiSoWN3h/38FGFBWQAVcCBllrDLKQAk0KS5liHooQJFRRpJAlgLJKCujSkEoDBmYESAZNABTiCmjTFDmv25RHgA))

Same idea as the Retina answer: replace every match of the regex `#.*#` with the result of transliterating space to `@` in the match. Pip can't match Retina's terseness for a pure regex problem--but it's not everyday that you can tie with Jelly, after all.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes

```
□⟑Ġvṅḣ$₴:Ṫ\@Ḟ$¤ptJṅ,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLilqHin5HEoHbhuYXhuKMk4oK0OuG5qlxcQOG4niTCpHB0SuG5hSwiLCIiLCIgICAgICAgICAjICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgICAgICAjIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgICAjICMjIyMgICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gIyAgICMjIyMjIyMjIyAgICAgICAgICAgXG4jIyAgIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMgICAgICAgICAgXG4jIyAjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjICAgIyMjIyAgXG4jIyAjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyAgIyMjIyMgXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyAjIyMjIyMjXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjXG4jIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIl0=)

### How?

```
□⟑Ġvṅḣ$₴:Ṫ\@Ḟ$¤ptJṅ,
□                    # All inputs wrapped in a list
 ⟑                   # Open an apply lambda, apply for each:
  Ġvṅ                # Group consecutive identical characters
     ḣ               # Head extract, push a[0], a[1:]
      $              # Swap
       ₴             # Print without a trailing newline
        :Ṫ           # Duplicate and remove the last item
          \@Ḟ        # Replace all spaces with "@"
             $       # Swap
              ¤p     # Prepend an empty string for the case that the list is empty
                t    # Last item
                 J   # Join top two things on the stack together
                  ṅ  # Join by nothing
                   , # Print with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 44 bytes

```
x=>x.replace(/# +#/g,s=>s.replace(/ /g,"@"))
```

Comment: Nice answer :) You can replace (hah!) `replaceAll(" ", ...` with `replace(/ /g,...` (removing the space) to save another three bytes too!

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <strike>108</strike> <strike>106</strike> 92 bytes

```
import re
n=1
while n: S,n=re.subn('# +#',lambda m:'#'+'@'*len(m.group(0)[2:])+'#',S)
print S
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 107 bytes

```
var f=function(x){return x.replace(/# +#/g, function(x){return "#"+new Array(x.length-1).join("@")+"#";})};
```

Ungolfed:

```
var f = function(x) {
    return x.replace(/# +#/g, function(x){
        return "#" + new Array(x.length - 1).join("@") + "#";
    })
};
```

Comment: I recommend that you (1) post a normally formatted version of your answer so it is easier to read and follow along and (2) look into to ES6... it could save you *a lot* of characters with your functions.

Comment: I'll post a normal version, but I'm not a ES6-type person.

Comment: @BobTheAwesome Why did you just suggest [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/21201) edit?

Comment: Oh goodness, I was attempting to fix the test-case error but I have [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xkcd-substitutions/jkgogmboalmaijfgfhfepckdgjeopfhk?hl=en) extension enabled in chrome, if you know xkcd. Sorry about that.

Comment: Besides the ES6 stuff: you don't need the space after the comma, you don't need the space after the second `return`, and you can remove the two semicolons, and it can just be `function f(x)...` or `f=function(x)...`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
Ỵ”@ẹ”#ṂrṀḟƲ$¦€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i2PGuY6PNy1E0gpP9zZVPRwZ8PDHfOPbVI5tOxR05rI/w93dD3cOe1w@///6urqXAowoKyACpBklLHKKAMl0KS4lCHqoQBFRhlJAlkKJKOsjCoFoTBkYEaAZNAATCGmjDJhGWA4AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 28 bytes

```apl
'# +#'⎕R{'@'@(' '∘=)⍵.Match}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X11ZQVtZ/VHf1KBqdQd1Bw11BfVHHTNsNR/1btXzTSxJzqj9n/aobcKj3r5HXc2Petc86t1yaL3xo7aJQC3BQc5AMsTDM/h/mgKQ5RXs76egrqQAA8oKqCAmDyGljF1KGSiDJheTpwzRAQWoUspIMshyYCllZVQ5CIUpBTMELIUGYCqxSCkTllJSBwA)