# Fill the histogram with water

Tags: code-golf

**Imagine a histogram.** Pour an infinite amount of water on to it. Then stop. How much water does the histogram hold?

Let's say we have a histogram with columns of these heights:

1 3 2 1 4 1 3

That would look like this:

```
    #
 #  # #
 ## # #
#######
1321413
```

If we pour an infinite amount of water on this histogram, some of those holes will fill up, and we'll end up with this:

```
    #
 #..#.#
 ##.#.#
#######
1321413
```

Apparently, this histogram can hold 5 slots of water.

**Your task**, should you choose to accept it, is to calculate the number of slots of water that a given histogram can hold. You may accept the input as a list, string, array, matrix, bitmap or whatever format you like. The output should be nothing but a single integer, in any format you like.

The input will only contain column heights between 1 and 1000, and the input size is between 1 and 1000 columns.

**Test cases:**

```
1 -> 0
2 1 2 -> 1
1 3 2 1 4 1 3 -> 5
1 3 5 7 6 4 2 1 -> 0
7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 7 -> 54
2 6 3 5 2 8 1 4 2 2 5 3 5 7 4 1 -> 35
```

If you're looking for possible ways to solve this problem, [here's four](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftcIcn8AmSY).

This is code golf, so the least bytes of source code wins.

Comment: Unfortunately we've had this challenge already: [Find the capacity of 2D printed objects](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69298/20260)

Comment: Ah, okey. Didn't find it while searching. We'll just mark this as a dupe then.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 16 bytes

```
(?<=# *) (?= *#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fw97GVllBS1NBw95WQUtZ8/9/BTBQ5lJQBtMIljKIpQxmKHMpwwAA) Link includes test case. Works by counting the spaces which are surrounded by `#`s.

Comment: How did you answer this 14 minute ago if this question was closed 22 minutes ago? :o

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum(min(max(l[:i+1]),max(l[i:]))-v for i,v in enumerate(l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU1BDsIgELz7ij1CxEOpbQ2Jv/BWOWCk6SZAG4Sqr6@UpsaLyWR3dmdndnyHfnB87s7X2Sh7uysw4hEtseiIVS9iWoH7QlK2DigkpYcJusEDsgnQgXbRaq@CJobS@dmj0XDxUYsdwOjRBegIujEGkuS2kLuWMygY8MRSKxPL8zHX8rutGDQM6ixwtviafPEPzZpcb@bET1swz6h@cpdv8gM)

Comment: How did you answer this 1 minute ago if this question was closed 22 minutes ago? :o